# Show only headers in Octopress RSS

Tags: rss, jekyll, octopress

I have a blog based on [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). It generates an `RSS`-feed, but that feed contains whole pages (posts) with images included.

How can I "shrink" it, so it would contain only headers of pages (posts)?

**Octopress**: 2.0
**Jekyll**: 2.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In feed.xml, instead of using `post.content`, you can use `post.excerpt`.

Two solutions :

#### 1 - Using octopress setup

Add a `<!-- more -->` in your posts to mark the limit between `post.excerpt` and `post.content`. `content` still contains both.

#### 2 - Using Jekyll default

Remove this line `excerpt_separator: <!--more-->` from your config file. As the default excerpt separator is `"\n\n"` (two new lines) excerpt will be created autoamtically.

#### Alternative solution

Use the [truncate](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#truncate) filter `{{ post.content | truncate: 200 | expand_urls: site.url | cdata_escape }}`

You will find [more information about excerpt in Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need, but I don't have `feed.xml`, only several `atom.xml` with the following content: http://pastebin.com/0R8zqJtF. I've changed `post.content` to `post.excerpt` in all of them, but that didn't change anything, unfortinatelly.

Comment: Check in your `_config.yml` file if you have an `excerpt_separator`. See documentation if you need one.

Comment: Yes, I do have one: `<!-- more -->`

Comment: check your jekyll version with `jekyll -v`

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was at work and PC was at home. Jekyll version is `2.0.3`, I've just checked.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much. The problem was that in the config: there was `<!--more-->` excerpt-separator (_without_ spaces) and in my posts there was `<!-- more -->` excerpt-separator (_with_ spaces). That's why your solution didn't work with my blog in the first time. I changed it and now everyting works just fine.